# Why can't my Cocoa Touch Class register UITableViewDataSource protocol methods to update storyboard's table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I wanted to try working with Cocoa Touch to create a table view but having issues. After I create the UITableViewController file and attach it to my storyboard table view's custom class, I expected to be able to see my table view update by implementing the protocol methods. I'm only seeing the initial state of the table view. I can change the background color, but I cant change the number of rows. I will attach my code below and an image displaying my reuse id/table view controller custom class in the storyboard. Please but I am struggling with this. Any recommendations?

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell123", for: indexPath)
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"
    return cell
    
}
}
```

[Storyboard file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtYT1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    
    return 0
}
```

You are returning **Zero** sections, so the table doesn't display any sections (or cells).

Change that to return **at least one** section:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    
    return 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I totally blew this one.